# How to filter webform nodes with a contextual filter that restricts webforms to those which have not been answered

Tags: views, nodes, webforms

I have a webform node display page that shows webform nodes that are available to individual users. Individual user accounts have a field called Project which has a Project name. This allows users to be segregated into projects. The webform nodes also have a taxonomy field that allows the project to which these webform nodes will be assigned to. I have setup a view which shows the list of webform nodes with a relationship to the Taxonomy Term on the Webform Node which is in turn related to the Taxonomy Term on the User Account. Then a contextual filter is setup which filters this display by the user ID of the logged in user. This far everything works fine and users are shown the Webforms nodes that are a part of the project they are a member of.

```
langcode: en
status: true
dependencies:
  config:
    - field.storage.node.body
    - field.storage.node.field_project_name
    - node.type.webform
    - system.menu.main
    - user.role.patient
  module:
    - node
    - taxonomy
    - text
    - user
    - webform
id: questionnaires_available_for_patients
label: 'Questionnaires available for Patients'
module: views
description: 'This is a view of questionnaires available for patients on the website. '
tag: ''
base_table: node_field_data
base_field: nid
display:
  default:
    id: default
    display_title: Default
    display_plugin: default
    position: 0
    display_options:
      title: 'Available Questionnaires'
      fields:
        counter:
          id: counter
          table: views
          field: counter
          relationship: none
          group_type: group
          admin_label: ''
          plugin_id: counter
          label: ''
          exclude: true
          alter:
            alter_text: false
            text: ''
            make_link: false
            path: ''
            absolute: false
            external: false
            replace_spaces: false
            path_case: none
            trim_whitespace: false
            alt: ''
            rel: ''
            link_class: ''
            prefix: ''
            suffix: ''
            target: ''
            nl2br: false
            max_length: 0
            word_boundary: true
            ellipsis: true
            more_link: false
            more_link_text: ''
            more_link_path: ''
            strip_tags: false
            trim: false
            preserve_tags: ''
            html: false
          element_type: ''
          element_class: ''
          element_label_type: ''
          element_label_class: ''
          element_label_colon: false
          element_wrapper_type: ''
          element_wrapper_class: ''
          element_default_classes: true
          empty: ''
          hide_empty: false
          empty_zero: false
          hide_alter_empty: true
          counter_start: 1
        title:
          id: title
          table: node_field_data
          field: title
          relationship: none
          group_type: group
          admin_label: ''
          entity_type: node
          entity_field: title
          plugin_id: field
          label: ''
          exclude: false
          alter:
            alter_text: true
            text: '{{ counter }}: {{ title }} '
            make_link: true
            path: '{{ title }}'
            absolute: false
            external: false
            replace_spaces: false
            path_case: none
            trim_whitespace: true
            alt: ''
            rel: ''
            link_class: ''
            prefix: ''
            suffix: ''
            target: ''
            nl2br: false
            max_length: 0
            word_boundary: false
            ellipsis: false
            more_link: false
            more_link_text: ''
            more_link_path: ''
            strip_tags: false
            trim: false
            preserve_tags: ''
            html: false
          element_type: h3
          element_class: ''
          element_label_type: ''
          element_label_class: ''
          element_label_colon: false
          element_wrapper_type: ''
          element_wrapper_class: ''
          element_default_classes: true
          empty: ''
          hide_empty: false
          empty_zero: false
          hide_alter_empty: true
          click_sort_column: value
          type: string
          settings:
            link_to_entity: true
          group_column: value
          group_columns: {  }
          group_rows: true
          delta_limit: 0
          delta_offset: 0
          delta_reversed: false
          delta_first_last: false
          multi_type: separator
          separator: ', '
          field_api_classes: false
        field_project_name:
          id: field_project_name
          table: node__field_project_name
          field: field_project_name
          relationship: none
          group_type: group
          admin_label: ''
          plugin_id: field
          label: Project
          exclude: true
          alter:
            alter_text: false
            text: ''
            make_link: false
            path: ''
            absolute: false
            external: false
            replace_spaces: false
            path_case: none
            trim_whitespace: false
            alt: ''
            rel: ''
            link_class: ''
            prefix: ''
            suffix: ''
            target: ''
            nl2br: false
            max_length: 0
            word_boundary: true
            ellipsis: true
            more_link: false
            more_link_text: ''
            more_link_path: ''
            strip_tags: false
            trim: false
            preserve_tags: ''
            html: false
          element_type: ''
          element_class: ''
          element_label_type: ''
          element_label_class: ''
          element_label_colon: true
          element_wrapper_type: ''
          element_wrapper_class: ''
          element_default_classes: true
          empty: ''
          hide_empty: false
          empty_zero: false
          hide_alter_empty: true
          click_sort_column: target_id
          type: entity_reference_label
          settings:
            link: false
          group_column: target_id
          group_columns: {  }
          group_rows: true
          delta_limit: 0
          delta_offset: 0
          delta_reversed: false
          delta_first_last: false
          multi_type: separator
          separator: ', '
          field_api_classes: false
        body:
          id: body
          table: node__body
          field: body
          relationship: none
          group_type: group
          admin_label: ''
          plugin_id: field
          label: ''
          exclude: false
          alter:
            alter_text: false
            text: ''
            make_link: false
            path: ''
            absolute: false
            external: false
            replace_spaces: false
            path_case: none
            trim_whitespace: false
            alt: ''
            rel: ''
            link_class: ''
            prefix: ''
            suffix: ''
            target: ''
            nl2br: false
            max_length: 0
            word_boundary: true
            ellipsis: true
            more_link: false
            more_link_text: ''
            more_link_path: ''
            strip_tags: false
            trim: false
            preserve_tags: ''
            html: false
          element_type: ''
          element_class: ''
          element_label_type: ''
          element_label_class: ''
          element_label_colon: false
          element_wrapper_type: ''
          element_wrapper_class: ''
          element_default_classes: true
          empty: ''
          hide_empty: false
          empty_zero: false
          hide_alter_empty: true
          click_sort_column: value
          type: text_default
          settings: {  }
          group_column: value
          group_columns: {  }
          group_rows: true
          delta_limit: 0
          delta_offset: 0
          delta_reversed: false
          delta_first_last: false
          multi_type: separator
          separator: ', '
          field_api_classes: false
        view_node:
          id: view_node
          table: node
          field: view_node
          relationship: none
          group_type: group
          admin_label: ''
          entity_type: node
          plugin_id: entity_link
          label: ''
          exclude: false
          alter:
            alter_text: false
            text: ''
            make_link: false
            path: ''
            absolute: false
            external: false
            replace_spaces: false
            path_case: none
            trim_whitespace: false
            alt: ''
            rel: ''
            link_class: ''
            prefix: ''
            suffix: ''
            target: ''
            nl2br: false
            max_length: 0
            word_boundary: true
            ellipsis: true
            more_link: false
            more_link_text: ''
            more_link_path: ''
            strip_tags: false
            trim: false
            preserve_tags: ''
            html: false
          element_type: strong
          element_class: button
          element_label_type: ''
          element_label_class: ''
          element_label_colon: false
          element_wrapper_type: ''
          element_wrapper_class: ''
          element_default_classes: true
          empty: ''
          hide_empty: false
          empty_zero: false
          hide_alter_empty: true
          text: 'Answer Questions'
          output_url_as_text: false
          absolute: false
      pager:
        type: mini
        options:
          offset: 0
          items_per_page: 10
          total_pages: null
          id: 0
          tags:
            next: ››
            previous: ‹‹
          expose:
            items_per_page: false
            items_per_page_label: 'Items per page'
            items_per_page_options: '5, 10, 25, 50'
            items_per_page_options_all: false
            items_per_page_options_all_label: '- All -'
            offset: false
            offset_label: Offset
      exposed_form:
        type: basic
        options:
          submit_button: Apply
          reset_button: false
          reset_button_label: Reset
          exposed_sorts_label: 'Sort by'
          expose_sort_order: true
          sort_asc_label: Asc
          sort_desc_label: Desc
      access:
        type: role
        options:
          role:
            patient: patient
      cache:
        type: tag
        options: {  }
      empty: {  }
      sorts:
        field_sequence_number_value:
          id: field_sequence_number_value
          table: node__field_sequence_number
          field: field_sequence_number_value
          relationship: none
          group_type: group
          admin_label: ''
          plugin_id: standard
          order: ASC
          expose:
            label: ''
            field_identifier: ''
          exposed: false
      arguments:
        uid:
          id: uid
          table: users_field_data
          field: uid
          relationship: reverse__user__field_project
          group_type: group
          admin_label: ''
          entity_type: user
          entity_field: uid
          plugin_id: user_uid
          default_action: default
          exception:
            value: all
            title_enable: false
            title: All
          title_enable: false
          title: ''
          default_argument_type: current_user
          default_argument_options: {  }
          default_argument_skip_url: false
          summary_options:
            base_path: ''
            count: true
            override: false
            items_per_page: 25
          summary:
            sort_order: asc
            number_of_records: 0
            format: default_summary
          specify_validation: false
          validate:
            type: none
            fail: 'not found'
          validate_options: {  }
          break_phrase: false
          not: false
      filters:
        status:
          id: status
          table: node_field_data
          field: status
          entity_type: node
          entity_field: status
          plugin_id: boolean
          value: '1'
          group: 1
          expose:
            operator: ''
        type:
          id: type
          table: node_field_data
          field: type
          entity_type: node
          entity_field: type
          plugin_id: bundle
          value:
            webform: webform
      style:
        type: default
        options:
          grouping: {  }
          row_class: ''
          default_row_class: true
      row:
        type: fields
        options:
          default_field_elements: true
          inline: {  }
          separator: ': '
          hide_empty: false
      query:
        type: views_query
        options:
          query_comment: ''
          disable_sql_rewrite: false
          distinct: true
          replica: false
          query_tags: {  }
      relationships:
        field_project_name:
          id: field_project_name
          table: node__field_project_name
          field: field_project_name
          relationship: none
          group_type: group
          admin_label: 'field_project_name: Taxonomy term (Project Name on Webform Node)'
          plugin_id: standard
          required: false
        reverse__user__field_project:
          id: reverse__user__field_project
          table: taxonomy_term_field_data
          field: reverse__user__field_project
          relationship: field_project_name
          group_type: group
          admin_label: 'field_project (On the User Account Page)'
          entity_type: taxonomy_term
          plugin_id: entity_reverse
          required: false
      header:
        area:
          id: area
          table: views
          field: area
          relationship: none
          group_type: group
          admin_label: ''
          plugin_id: text
          empty: false
          content:
            value: '<h4>Dear {{ arguments.uid }} , as a member of the {{ field_project_name }} study the following questionnaires are available to you. Please answer them by clicking the Answer Question button. </h4>'
            format: restricted_html
          tokenize: true
      footer: {  }
      display_extenders: {  }
    cache_metadata:
      max-age: -1
      contexts:
        - 'languages:language_content'
        - 'languages:language_interface'
        - url
        - url.query_args
        - user
        - 'user.node_grants:view'
        - user.roles
      tags:
        - 'config:field.storage.node.body'
        - 'config:field.storage.node.field_project_name'
  page_1:
    id: page_1
    display_title: Page
    display_plugin: page
    position: 1
    display_options:
      rendering_language: '***LANGUAGE_language_interface***'
      display_extenders: {  }
      path: available-questionnaires
      menu:
        type: normal
        title: Questionnaires
        menu_name: main
        parent: ''
    cache_metadata:
      max-age: -1
      contexts:
        - 'languages:language_interface'
        - url
        - url.query_args
        - user
        - 'user.node_grants:view'
        - user.roles
      tags:
        - 'config:field.storage.node.body'
        - 'config:field.storage.node.field_project_name'
```

Now I would like to ensure that the page shows the questionnaires only if they have not been answered by the user that day. That is if there are 3 forms available for the person, and they have filled in the first form, then after visiting the same page again that day the webform node that was filled before would not be displayed in the list.

Logically this would imply that I have a filter which filters the webform node by the date on which associated webform was submitted by the user.

When I try to add another relationship to the Webform submission done by the user however the webform nodes are no longer visible. I am not getting any error message that would help on this further also.